# Using min to get lowest key and value from dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, min

Dictionary:

```
d = {u'A': 240, u'B': 242, u'C': 243}
```

---

I have successfully managed to identify the lowest key using the following code:

```
min_ = min(d, key=d.get)
```

Output:

```
A
```

I'd like to make the output contain the value as well:

`A, 240`

---

*Note*:

I'd like to avoid the use of `lambda` if possible

Comment: `d[min_]` gives you the value

Comment: You have a `dict`. You have a key, and you want a value. I think you could connect the dots.

Comment: Alternatively, `min(d.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))`.

Comment: *I'd like to avoid the use of lambda if possible*. Please don't place arbitrary restrictions without at least *explaining why*. **Why** is a lambda unacceptable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply `min` to the dictionary *items* then:

```
from operator import itemgetter

min(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1))
```

I used the [`operator.itemgetter()` callable](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to retrieve the `value` from each `(key, value)` pair, but you could also use `lambda pair: pair[1]`. The latter will be slightly slower as it involves dropping back into a Python call frame.

Demo:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> d = {u'A': 240, u'B': 242, u'C': 243}
>>> min(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1))
(u'A', 240)
```

Comment: Awesome, Thanks for this! Is there a simple way to remove the "Unnecessary Characters" i.e. "( u ' )", so I'm left with `A, 240`?

Comment: @LearningToPython: you are echoing or printing a *tuple*, so `repr()` is used; tuples are not meant to end-user friendly, they only have a debugging-friendly representation. If you want to format that to something else, use string formatting. `'{}, {}'.format(*result)` would format it the way you want it (put the two values into a string with a comma and a space).

Comment: Thanks - I found I could doing `x[0]` and `x[1]` gave me the result